# XML Schema how to write string with childless element

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I have an XML file. I am trying to generate xsd schema file. My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd" id="62378">

  <title>Beans On Toast</title>
  <ingredients>
     <item quantity="1" unit="slice">bread</item>
     <item quantity="1" unit="can">bakedbeans</item>        
  </ingredients> 
</recipe>
```

My schema file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="recipe" type="recipeType"/>
<xs:complexType name="recipeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ingredients" type="ingredientsType"/>           
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ingredientsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="item" type="itemType"/>
    </xs:sequence>    
</xs:complexType>          

<xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="unit" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>    
</xs:schema>
```

I am getting error while validating. I know the reason. Because I have failed to define element item type = xs:string because I have to write complexType("itemType") for attributes. Can anyone please solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need attributes, you have to use a `complexType`. But if you also need simple content, then you can define your `complexType` as containing `simpleContent` and extend it with attributes using a base simple type

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:attribute name="unit" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This will allow:

```
<item quantity="1" unit="slice">bread</item>
```

You still need to allow more than one `<item>` element inside `ingredientsType`. If you can have unlimited items, you can use:

```
<xs:complexType name="ingredientsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="item" type="itemType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>    
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: thanks. Also described here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_text.asp

Comment: Can you please give another explanation? I need sequence for (title,ingredients) but why I have to write sequence in the next block? Otherwise it is giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `itemType` as mixed (use `mixed='true'` on the complex type definition).